# Tratamento de Exceção não funciona quando faz divisão por zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, exceção

Preciso ler um conjunto de valores e informar a divisão entre eles, independente de ser positivo ou negativo. O problema fala que se ocorrer uma divisão por zero deve ser exibida uma mensagem dizendo "divisao impossivel".

Eu resolvi fazer essa questão usando o comando `try`/`except`, já que é a única alternativa que não retornaria uma mensagem de erro com uma divisão por zero, mas mesmo usando esse comando está sendo retornada uma mensagem de erro e não exibe a mensagem que a questão pede.

```
N = int(input())

for i in range(0, N):
    try:
       X, Y = input().split(" ")

       X = float(X)
       Y = float(Y)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
       print('divisao impossivel')
    else:
       divisao = X / Y

       print(divisao)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A divisão deveria estar dentro da tentativa, depois que a tentativa acabou e já tratou o possível erro que não tem como acontecer não adianta fazer a divisão porque ali o erro não será tratado. Seria algo assim:

```
N = int(input())
for i in range(0, N):
    try:
       X, Y = input().split(" ")
       X = float(X)
       Y = float(Y)
       divisao = X / Y
       print(divisao)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
       print('divisao impossivel')
```

Mas isso não é correto.

Há outros erros que não foram tratados, e que é complicado tratar sem ser pela exceção.

E acho que um erro que é facilmente detectado deveria fazê-lo em vez de deixar a exceção estourar. Então ao contrário do que está escrito na pergunta capturar a exceção não é a única alternativa para resolver isso.

E se der erro imagino que não deve avançar na contagem de itens como está fazendo.

Não é um erro, mas o pessoal de Python pegou essa maneira triste de pegar os dados em uma linhas só que incentiva digitar coisas erradas. Eu mudaria isso, mas pode ser que o exercício pede assim, o que é uma forma de ensinar fazer coisas confusa, eu repensaria em algo que vai por esse caminho como sendo uma boa referência.

Aí ficaria quase isto;

```
n = int(input())
i = 0
while i < n:
    try:
        x, y = input().split(" ")
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        if y != 0:
           print(x / y)
           i += 1
        else:
            print('divisao impossivel')
    except ValueError:
       print('formato digitado errado')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Xz5JAz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qqiivxrs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Math/ZeroDivision.py).

Na verdade ainda pode dar erro quando digita o `n`, faça o tratamento desse caso.

Comment: Poderia me explicar porque essa maneira de ler os dados em uma única linha não é apropriado? A minha primeira linguagem de programação é o Python.

Comment: Porque é muito fácil digitar errado, a pessoa tem que saber que tem que colocar um espaço.

Answer (score -1):

Tmb me deparei com esse problema de mensagem de erro do sistema.
A solucão foi colocar "divisao impossivel" antes do comando para dividir:

```
    print('QUANTOS CASOS VAI DIGITAR? ', end='')
    n = int(input())
    
    for i in range(n):
        print('entre com o numerador: ', end='')
        num = int(input())
        print('entre com o denominador: ', end='')
        den = int(input())         
        if den == 0:
            print("DIVISAO IMPOSSIVEL")

# qndo vc coloca nessa posicao, antes da divisao, o sistema nao da erro

        else:
            div = num / den
            print(f'DIVISAO = {div:.2f}')

# estava posicionando o "divisao impossivel" abaixo do comando de divisao.
# onde o erro do sistema aparecia
```